# How to find the underlying OS from Startup class

Tags: asp.net-core

I would like to have a different appsettings for MacOS and Windows. How can I retrieve from the Startup class the OS running my app in order to load the right appsettings.json ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public Startup(
        IConfiguration configuration, 
        IHostingEnvironment env

        )
    {

          var os = RuntimeInformation.OSDescription + " " + RuntimeInformation.OSArchitecture.ToString();

    }
```